# Country and city in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Is there a country and city gem where user will be able to select a country and based on selected country he will select a city?

Comment: You can try carmen gem to achieve this, https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails or https://rubygems.org/gems/country_state_select

Comment: But carmen is only for country I think and it is not actively maintained

Comment: no, it supports regions too, you can see demo link on the same page https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails

Comment: Yes I know it support region but if there is one that support cities it would be better

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are a few gems you can try :

You can try [`country_select`](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)

You can try [`countries`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) which will give you countries list as well as some extra information.

You can try [`carmen-rails`](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails) and [here](http://carmen-rails-demo.herokuapp.com/) is the demo you can see.

Comment: the carmen gem seem to be a good one it would be better if there is a gem that provide city instead of country region

Answer (score 1):

[city-state gem](https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state) might be in help.

Country list:

```
CS.countries
```

City list:

```
CS.cities(:sp, :br)
```

The country is an optional argument. city-state always uses the last country that you used.

Answer (score 0):

I have also this issue,but now solved..

You can [use](https://rubygems.org/gems/country_state_select/versions/3.0.1) `gem 'country_state_select'`